# Is "git log --pretty=<pretty format>" a porcelain or plumbing command?

Tags: git, git-log

I am creating some scripts and programs that fetch commit information using

```
git log --pretty=<my format> -1 <commit>
```

I wonder if the output of this command is suitable to be parsed by programs (plumbing) or only meant to be presented to humans (porcelain). For example, in some projects I am fetching commit SHA + author name + commit summary with this:

```
git log --pretty="%H%n%an%n%s" -1 HEAD
```

And then I split the output string by the newline character (I'm on Linux).

Besides, in some cases I also do something like this:

```
git log --pretty='[%h] %an: %s' -1 HEAD
```

And then parse the result with the following regex, expecting that a short SHA, the author name and the commit summary are in the captured groups:

```
^\[(\w+)\] ([^:]+): (.*)$
```

Is it a good approach? If not, what is the preferred way to programmatically get information about commits?

Comment: I prefer it is an porcelain command, due to this (off topic) clue: In Pro Git v2, [Chapter 10.1](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Plumbing-and-Porcelain#_plumbing_porcelain) says "this book’s first nine chapters deal almost exclusively with porcelain commands", and `git log`, with machine-oriented format, are mentioned [in Chapter 2.3](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Viewing-the-Commit-History), which is in "this book's first nine chapters".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`git log` is a porcelain command.

It actually performs quite a disparate number of tasks — combining walking the revision graph, `git diff` and `git grep` and whatnot.

A plumbing way to do someting like

```
git log --pretty='[%h] %an: %s' -1 HEAD
```

is to combine `git show-ref` with `git cat-file` and parse the result—something like

```
git cat-file commit `git show-ref -s HEAD` |
  while read line; do
    # do some processing
  done
```

---

Actually the root Git's manual page, `git(1)`—run `git help git` to read it—contains the breakdown of commands into porcelain and plumbing layers.

Comment: `git cat-file commit <ref>` seems like a reliable plumbing command, but the output appears to be more difficult to parse than that of `git log --pretty`. Any better solution?

Comment: I cannot see what's complex about it: it's a header of lines of the form `^key SP value LF$` separated by a blank line `^LF LF$` from the content. So basically you read all the lines until an empty one and look for specific keywords such as `author` and/or `committer`. I mean, can you elaborate on what particular difficulty you have with it?

Comment: Hi, can you take a look at my own answer and give some comments? (+1 for your answer)

Answer (score 4):

I agree with [kostix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53582586/1256452); `git log` is a porcelain command.  But the problem here is that there are some things `git log` can do that are too difficult to do with other commands, so we can sometimes make `git log` *act like* a plumbing command.

The key distinction between plumbing and porcelain shows up when comparing, e.g., `git branch` and `git tag` to `git for-each-ref`, or `git diff` to `git diff-tree` and `git diff-files` and `git diff-index`.  It's not how many porcelains there are per plumbing.  Here, for instance, the plumbing `git for-each-ref` has two separate porcelain front ends, while the single front-end `git diff` has three plumbing back-ends.  No, the key is that `git diff` *changes its behavior* based on user-selected configuration items:

```
diff.algorithm
diff.dirstat
diff.renameLimit
diff.renames
diff.statGraphWidth
diff.submodule
```

and so on.  The plumbing versions *ignore all user configuration*, so that a script you write behaves the same for Alice, Bob, Carol, and Dave, even though they have different settings.

When using this definition, we can decide whether `git log` *acts like* a plumbing command.  This requires enumerating all the `git log` configuration options.  Unfortunately, there's no clean way to do that—more options can be added at any time, and some have been added over time.

Here's a list I found by scraping through the `git log` and `git config` manual.  Note that I omit all the diff-oriented ones (e.g., `color.diff` and the `diff.*` items mentioned above) as there are plumbing commands to handle the equivalent of `-p` in `git log` (though you must work through one commit at a time).

```
color.decorate.<slot>
core.notesRef
format.pretty
i18n.logOutputEncoding
log.abbrevCommit
log.date
log.decorate
log.follow
log.graphColors
log.mailmap
log.showRoot
log.showSignature
notes.displayRef
pretty.<name>
```

So, let's say we want to get the committer date from some particular commit, formatted some particular way.  To do that we might run:

```
git log --no-walk --pretty=format:%cd
```

We find in the main `git log` documentation that pretty format `%cd` is described this way:

> %cd: committer date (format respects --date= option)

We failed to give a `--date=` option, so `git log` will look up the `log.date` setting.  That's a user-configuration option, and our `git log` output will depend on the *user's* choice, rather than ours.

To make this `git log` *act like* a plumbing command, then, we must override the `log.date` configuration setting, with, e.g., `--date=default` or `-c log.date=default`:

```
git -c log.date=default log --no-walk --pretty=format:%cd
```

or:

```
git log --no-walk --date=default --pretty=format:%cd
```

Ideally, Git should have either a `plog` command that is defined as *plumbing variant of git log*, or a `git format-log-metadata` plumbing command that takes the `--pretty=<directives>` options and formats log metadata.  Since it doesn't, it's up to anyone writing a script, that needs `git log --pretty=format:...` output, to make sure that they know about configuration options that might affect them.

Comment: Does that mean, even if it isn't strictly a plumbing command, I can still override related settings and expect plumbing results?

Comment: @iBug: Yes. The problem is that in the future, because `git log` is really porcelain, someone might *add a new configuration item* that you can't tell that you must override yet, because right now you don't *need* to override it.

Comment: Hi, can you take a look at my own answer and give some comments? (+1 for your answer)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to kostic and torek for their answers.

Despite what they answered, I believe that *some* of the pretty format options can be safely treated as plumbing (i.e. safe to be parsed by programs). Examples include

- `%H` for full commit SHA
- `%T` for full tree SHA
- `%P` for full parent SHAs
- `%an`, `%cn`, `%ae`, `%ce`, `%at`, `%ct` for author/committer name/email/date (Unix). Also RFC 2822 and ISO 8601 style times are reliable `%aD`, `%cD`, `%aI`, `%cI`
- `%s` for commit summary
- `%G?` for signature status
- `%n` for a newline (lol...)

Yes, while format specifiers like `%ad` and `%cN` can be affected by user settings, it's unlikely that the above ones do. So I have decided that my current code that parses the output of `git log` with a pretty format combined from above specifiers, is safe and not error-prone.

Comment: @jthill How is it different from `git log`?

Comment: It's got the core-command aka plumbing guarantees, its output's intended for your use.

Comment: It seems pretty safe to use these directives with `--pretty={,t}format` / `--format=`, yes. Curiously, while these mostly do work with `git rev-list`, they're not listed as options for it. But rev-list and log are built from the same source file and mostly handle the same arguments. Unfortunately `git rev-list` behaves poorly when used with `--format`s!

Comment: @torek Can you elaborate a bit about the last sentence? I'm very curious about how `git rev-list` behaves poorly with pretty formats.

Comment: Just try it: `git log --pretty=format:"%H %cn" HEAD` vs `git rev-list --pretty=format:"%H %cn" HEAD`. Sure, you can throw out every other line, but why should you *have* to?

Comment: @torek There's zero difficulty for me to match the line with `^commit [0-9a-f]{40}$` and then throw it away.

Comment: Sure, but again, why should you *have* to? That's like having `git for-each-ref` print the date on every other line, or something. rev-list is a plumbing command; it should behave like one. (Also, if/when Git switches to SHA3-256, that `{40}` will be wrong.)

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to [kostix's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53582586): for me, `git show-ref -s HEAD` does not output anything and returns with exit code 1.

Instead of:

```
git cat-file commit `git show-ref -s HEAD`
```

I use:

```
git cat-file commit `git show-ref --head -s HEAD`
```

or:

```
git cat-file commit `git rev-parse HEAD`
```