# Is it possible to count the number of parents a specific commit has?

Tags: git

Most commits have 1 parent commit. However, some commits have multiple parents. For instance, merge commits that were created under the `--no-ff` (no fast-forward) flag have at least 2 parents.

Is there a command in git that shows the exact number of parents a specific commit has?

Comment: I think 1 or 2 are really the only common number of parents. While I think in theory any number is possible, I don't know of any workflows that creates >2 parents. Edit: [there are samples of it in the wild](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/314215/can-a-git-commit-have-more-than-2-parents).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To view the list of parent commits:

```
git show -s --format=%p [commit-id]
```

To just show the number of parents:

```
git show -s --format=%p [commit-id] | wc -w
```

Explanation:

- `-s` is short for `--no-patch` which [suppresses the diff output](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show#Documentation/git-show.txt--s).
- `%p` [displays only the parents](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show#Documentation/git-show.txt-empem) in the format.
- `wc` is [word count](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wc_(Unix)) in *nix shells and `-w` is only words.

Answer (score 3):

For a casual or human-readable answer, use `git show` as in [TTT's post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68412902/1426891).

However, despite the clean use of `--format`, the output of `git show` is allowed to change: it is a ["porcelain command"](https://git-scm.com/docs/git#_high_level_commands_porcelain) in `git`'s "plumbing/porcelain separation". ([The same is true of `git log --format`.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53581762/1426891)) Changes might be unlikely, but you might also see errors and other human-directed output as `git show` is intended for human consumption rather than script consumption.

For a more rigorous or spec-guaranteed list of parents, suitable for long-lived shell scripts or tool integration, you'll want to use a [plumbing command](https://git-scm.com/docs/git#_low_level_commands_plumbing) like `git cat-file`, similar to [extracting a commit date without `git log`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52708548/1426891).

```
git cat-file -p [commit-id] | sed -ne '/^$/q;/^parent/p' | wc -l
```

- `git cat-file -p` will pretty-print the object with the given ID. Revisions like `HEAD` also work here.
- `sed` here will both filter and truncate the output:

  - `-n` suppresses all output.
  - `-e` uses a script specified on the command line.
  - `/^$/q` tells `sed` to quit if it sees a blank line, like the one separating commit metadata from its message. This prevents misinterpreting the word "parent" in your commit body text.
  - `;` separates `sed` commands.
  - `/^parent/p` tells `sed` to print only the lines that start with `parent`, overriding `-n`.
- `wc -l` prints the number of resulting lines.

Once again, for most cases `git show` is a more idiomatic way of doing this, since it reads and parses the commit all in one command and has already been written with edge-cases and oddities in mind. However, for developers of long-lived `git` tools, plumbing commands might be a more guaranteed solution.

Comment: Consider also `git rev-list --no-walk --parents <hash> | wc -w` (though you then have to subtract 1 or otherwise fuss about with the output).

Answer (score 3):

To programmatically count the number of parents without using any pipes, you can use

```
git rev-list --no-walk --count --skip=1 <commit> <commit>^@
```

If you know that `<commit>` has a non-zero number of parents (i.e. it's not a root commit), this can be simplified to

```
git rev-list --no-walk --count <commit>^@
```

Explanation:

- `git rev-list --no-walk` will interpret and print a list of all the revisions you give it (effectively the same as `git rev-parse`)
- `--count` tells rev-list that instead of printing the list, it should print a count of the number of revisions
- If `<commit>` has no parents, then `<commit>^@` doesn't specify any revisions, so `git rev-list` will print its usage message (just like if we ran it with no arguments). To circumvent this, we pass `--skip=1` and an extra revision for it to skip over (in this case `<commit>`).

credit to @jthill's comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3824050/telling-if-a-git-commit-is-a-merge-revert-commit#comment82244548_13956422) for the idea to use `rev-list --no-walk --count`

P.S. `rev-list` is also a plumbing command, so doesn't have the problems @Jeff Bowman pointed out in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68413715/4490331)

Comment: With Git 2.40.1, that `--skip=1 <commit>` workaround doesn't seem to be necessary any longer; I also get a count of `0` on the root commit without it.